# When I create a “Public rigidbody” in vs code, and apply it to a player in unity, i cant access the rigidbody i created in code. Any ideas as to why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

This is what the c# code looks like. I took this from the YouTube channel “Brackeys” tutorial. The rigid body “player” should show up when i apply it to the player in unity, but it doesn’t so i cant connect the players rigidbody to the code

```
public rigidbody player;

void start 
{
    player.addForce(0,0,1000);
}
// should add a force when game starts
```

Comment: For starters `Rigidbody`,  `Start` and `AddFoce` are all capitalized .... And then you mean it isn't appearing in the Inspector right? ... do you get errors in the console -> fix all compiler errors then it will show up

Comment: I have them all capitalized in the actual code, my bad. But yes, in unity when i attached the script to the “player”, the the rigidbody doesnt show up under the script

Answer (score 0):

C# is case sensitive. `Rigidbody` is not the same as `rigidbody`. You need to capitalize your function calls along with add the parenthesis to Start().

```cs
public Rigidbody player;

void Start()
{
    player.AddForce(0,0,1000);
}
```

Make sure that when you're following a tutorial, you capitalize the same way that the person teaching the tutorial does. You may also benefit from some more [info on C# basics.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/CSharp-Fundamentals-for-Absolute-Beginners/)

Comment: [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo)

Comment: @derHugo Oh I didnt know this was how stuff like this is usually handled on SO, sorry about that. I'll keep it in mind the next time I post an answer